# iphone 4 - loading images x old devices

Tags: iphone, ipad

Apple says you must have @2x versions of your images and use a stuff like

```
UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button"]; // without the extension
```

That will select the lowres and hires versions of Button image, depending on the iPhone version (3G/3GS or 4). But what if the app is for iPad too?

Will the iPad load the Button image even if I don't specify the extension?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button"]; // without the extension
```

or

```
UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"]; // with the extension
```

will work on iOS4, since apple basically discourage you from using any other image than PNG you can omit the exertion.

Both work for @2x.png files as well. Make sure the @2x files have been added to your project.

Comment: I've done that but the images are not loading in hires... at least not on the simulator (no iPhone 4 soon on my country). Can you please confirm if the hires images load on the simulator, once you have them on your project? thanks!

Answer (score 6):

> Will the iPad load the Button image even if I don't specify the extension?

No. [From the doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW10):

- **Special Considerations**

  On iOS 4 and later, the name of the file is not required to specify the filename extension. *Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension.*

Since iPad is running 3.2, you need to include the `.png` part. However, writing

```
UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"];
```

will not prevent the system from finding `Button@2x.png` on 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

as a complement to the answer, I must mention [this page](http://atastypixel.com/blog/uiimage-resolution-independence-and-the-iphone-4s-retina-display/#more-1951):

the problem is that the SDK is broken and despite Apple mentioning that other methods beyond imageNamed load the @2x images, they don't. Shame on Apple to make us lose time when their SDK is broken.

the mentioned link has the solution for the problem, using a way around.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will load the standard (lores) version.

Edit: Don't forget to test on the simulator or real device, as there are some twiddles, but imageNamed: has proven to work well so far.